# Multiple threads HashTable in java

Tags: java, multithreading, hashtable

MainThread has a HashTable, which save a mapping from customId to SubThread Object, and put task to map. SubThread remove task from map.
how to avoiding this problem?

thread 1:

```
public void start()
{
        subThreadMap = new Hashtable<Integer, SubThread>();
        while(true)
        {
            List<CloudPusherTaskInfo> taskInfos = TestDao.getTasks();

        for (CloudPusherTaskInfo task : taskInfos)
        {
            distribute(task);
        }
    }
}

private void distribute(CloudPusherTaskInfo task)
{
    SubThread subThread = null;

    if(subThreadMap.containsKey(task.getCustomerId()))
    {
        /*
         * if subThread exist, add a task to it
         */
        subThread = subThreadMap.get(task.getCustomerId());

/* -----at this point, the other subThread maybe end, and return null--------*/

        subThread.add(task);
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         * if subThread is not exist, create a new subthread, then add a task and run it 
         */
        SubThread newThread = createNewSubThread(task.getCustomerId());
        subThread = subThreadMap.put(task.getCustomerId(), newThread);
        newThread.add(task);
        new Thread(newThread).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem actually??? which problem do you want to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, it is possible for the subThread to have finished its tasks and ended between the call to `subThreadMap.containsKey()` and `subThreadMap.get()`.

Don't reinvent the wheel.  You should look at the classes in package `java.util.concurrent`, which provides all the functionality you need to accomplish thread pooling and task execution.

Answer (score 1):

The HashTable  `Hashtable<Integer, SubThread>();` is not needed if its primary reason is to get Thread objects and start them. Make the CloudPusherTaskInfo implement the Runnable interface and  then use the `Executor.execute(new CloudPusherTaskInfo())`. Or you could hold the CloudPusherTaskInfo tasks in a List and execute them one after another.